# htaccess doesn't redirect to ssl

Tags: .htaccess, https

My htaccess file has me utterly confused. First it gave me a mixed content warning on chrome whilst working properly, after changing it it no longer does that, but also somehow no longer redirects the main domain to https.

This is what I want:

- Redirect `/index.php` to `/`
- Redirect `www` to `non-www`
- Redirect `non-https` to `https`

This is what my .htaccess file looks like right now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I honestly don't see any issues with it. It works fine if I go directly to `/index.php`, it works fine when going directly to `https://...` or `www.domain.net` but it doesn't work when I go to the `domain.net`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many issues at your code like these two lines :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

you match all `https` and `www` and not when they not exist

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.growconomy.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php$    /  [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I'm not really that familiar with htaccess, I see how this makes sense now. I was completely lost to be honest

Answer (score 1):

You're only including www as a subdomain to redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

You might remove it or change it to something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

Comment: now it redirects to localhost... I'm not sure what's happening here. Your reply makes sense, because it's only selecting urls with www so not the domain without www. I tried removing the line completely and changing it as well. I also think safari perceives the file differently than chrome. I cleared cache on both.

Comment: If this is a public URL, you also need to have these domains mapped in your dns records.  You would do this via whoever you've registered your domain name with (godaddy, networksolutions, etc).

If this is a private url you probably actually need to remove this domain from your /etc/hosts file (on linux machines) because if it's going to localhost the domain would have had be mapped to localhost in your etc file already.

Comment: The localhost issue was safari-only (strangely), even after clearing cache. I'm glad it works now, and also want to thank you for your effort!